# Conditionally exclude installing node dependency from package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an ExpressJS application. I want to execute it on Lambda functions and EC2.

In order to execute it on Lambda functions, I use the `@vendia/serverless-express` package.

In order to execute it on EC2, I want to exclude the installation of `@vendia/serverless-express`.

The env variable `TYPE` makes it possible to distinguish between the two deployments.

Since, `@vendia/serverless-express` is part of my `dependencies` in `package.json` it gets installed on EC2 as well. Is there a way to exclude it using the `TYPE` environment variable for EC2 deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a block in your package.json such as:

```
{
    ...
    "serverlessDependencies":
    {
        "@vendia/serverless-express": "*"
    },
    ...
}
```

And then, use a library called [handpick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handpick) to select when to install them.

Then write a bash script that will evaluate `NODE_ENV` and decide what to do:

pseudo code:

```
npm install
if(NODE_ENV == 'serverless')
   npx handpick --target=serverlessDependencies
```

Comment: So, on which node script in package.json do I execute the bash script.

Comment: If npm install is used, it will go in a loop right?

Comment: No. Create a bash script and call it using `./install-script.sh`

Comment: I suggest to use a reference over slightly dangerous *
https://henryruhs.gitbook.io/handpick/examples/reference